# References on the Evaluation of Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request

**What are the best introductory resources for learning how to evaluate tricky series?**

I don't have any specific series in mind, I am looking for general methods to solve a variety of series. The target audience would hopefully be advanced undergraduates or maybe beginning graduates. The resources could be print books, ebooks, lecture notes, video lectures, etc.

Comment: You are using the same index in both sums.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: maybe you should take the 3 seconds or so to read the question.

Comment: @RonGordon: The post has been changed!

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal I edited the question so as to get the the point more quickly.

Comment: @MathNerd: What you are asking is clear from the title!