# References on evaluating sums of infinite series

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, reference-request

Does anyone know any textbooks/online resources that talk extensively about evaluating the sums of infinite series? Tons exist for identifying when they converge or not, but I need something exploring the actual evaluation.

A previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/730590/references-on-the-evaluation-of-series) seems to have 0 responses.

Comment: This is because there aren't general rules for evaluating such series. There are certainly techniques, but "most" series which don't have a "good" closed form.

Comment: "inside impossible integrals and series" and similar

Comment: You might look at Herbert S. Wilf, [Generatingfunctionology](https://www.google.ca/books/edition/Generatingfunctionology/XOPMBQAAQBAJ)

Comment: See **An Introduction to the Operations with Series** by Isaac Joachim Schwatt ([1924](https://books.google.com/books?id=IJttAAAAMAAJ); reprinted with corrections by Chelsea Publishing Company [in 1962](https://archive.org/details/introductiontoop00schw_0)). A google-books .pdf file of the 1924 edition is freely available where I'm at, and the Internet Archive has a copy of the 1962 edition for borrowing. Schwatt's book is rather advanced. For something more elementary, see (parts of) [**Real Infinite Series**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0883857456) by Bonar/Khoury (2006).

Comment: See also (parts of) the books in my answer to [Other Useful Series Tests](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/984345/13130).